# Equality between two functions and parameters correspondence

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Let $f_1(t) = Acos(\omega_1 t + \phi_1)$ and $f_2(t) = Bcos(\omega_2 t + \phi_2)$ with $\omega_1,\omega_2 > 0$. Now say that the following is true :

$$\forall t : f_1(t) = f_2(t)$$

Although it might seem obvious, is it possible to algebraically prove that $A = B$, $\omega_1 = \omega_2$ and that $\phi_1 = \phi_2 + 2k\pi$ with $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ ?

Comment: It's a good question but you need to add that $\omega_1, \omega_2 > 0$ because $\omega_1 = -\omega_2$ is allowed as well in this formulation. See $\cos(t) = \cos(-t)$. Petty I know : )

Comment: @Squid You're right! I'm correcting for that in my question :)